# How can getters/setters be ignored in the PMD CommentRequired rule?

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

I want to use PMDs [CommentRequired](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.2/pmd-java/rules/java/comments.html) rule, but don't want it to be applied to java bean getters/setters.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28728177/1466267) I tried the following configuration:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/comments.xml/CommentRequired">
    <properties>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="./ancestor::MethodDeclaration/MethodDeclarator/NodeToken[@tokenImage='(get|is|set).*']"/>
        <property name="fieldCommentRequirement" value="Ignored"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

However PMD still reports that some getters in my code need a comment.

What is the correct XPath expression to suppress the rule for getters/setters and on which schema are the PMD XPath expressions based upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the [PMD XPath rule tutorial](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.2/customizing/xpathruletutorial.html) and playing around with the PMD Designer the following does work for me:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/java/comments.xml/CommentRequired">
    <properties>
        <property name="violationSuppressXPath" value="//ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration/MethodDeclaration/MethodDeclarator[matches(@Image,'(get|is|set)[\p{Lu}].*') and not(FormalParameters/FormalParameter)]"/>
        <property name="fieldCommentRequirement" value="Ignored"/>
    </properties>
</rule>
```

To get a better grasp on the AST that PMD is using, one can have a look at the javadoc of it: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.0/apidocs/net/sourceforge/pmd/lang/java/ast/package-summary.html

Comment: I tried adding the xpath above xpath expression, but that also ignores static analysis for `foo()` method, considering that their is either `setBoo()` or `getBob()`method. Whereas it should only silent the scan for setters and getters!